# Problems with tensorflow hub: Table not initialized

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I am trying to use tf_hub for universal-sentence-encoder-large when I have the following problem:

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Table not initialized.
```

It seems that TensorFlow thinks I did not run init op, but actually, I have run the init op:

```
embed = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3")
embeddings = embed([
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."])    
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    embeddings = sess.run(embeddings)

    print(embeddings)
```

The same code structure has been fine with other tf_hub models like `elmo`.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like to use this tensorflow hub, I need to run an addtional initializer:

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
table_init = tf.tables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([init, table_init])
    embeddings_ = sess.run(embeddings)

    print(embeddings)
```

Comment: Not sure why but it didn't help me. Still throws error in production.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```py
with tf.train.SingularMonitoredSession() as sess:
  ...
```

which does all standard initializations by itself (including "shared resources", for which there was no public API last time I checked).